# How many examples are statically needed for a random process output?

Tags: statistics

I am running an algorithm which is based on random selection of some variables and it produces some results. The time consumption of this algorithm is depend on those random initialization. Each running time is different and it is not depend on previous running.

I want to repeat ( N times) this process and get the average response time of this algorithm. Statically, how to get N to be sure that the average is acceptable and not far from the reality? any test should I do such as t-test or Z-test? Can anyone in this area help me, what should i do? And how can I say that the average is accurate enough?
Thanks

Comment: The more the better. That is all you can expect if you do not want to make additional calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Say your $N$ samples are $x_1,...x_N$. Then the "true mean" can be estimated by the "sample mean":
$$E(x) \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$$
And the error of this estimation can be estimated by
$$Err_{E(x)} \approx \sqrt{\frac{Var(x)}{N}}$$
where $Var(x)$ is the variance of the sample. This error estimate works very well if $x$ is (approximately) normal distributed (which is often a reasonable assumption if you don't know more details). If it is not, additional statistical tests might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know whether the data are from a distribution that is approximately normal. If so
the formula to get the required $n$ is straightforward.

If the observations are $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ then the sample mean
is $\bar X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and the sample standard deviation is
$S = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n-1}}.$ The sample
mean estimates the population mean $\mu,$ but one can never know
*exactly* how precisely.

A 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is of
the form $\bar X \pm t^* S/\sqrt{n},$ where $t^*$ cuts 2.5% of the
probability from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with
$n - 1$ degrees of freedom. For confidence
level 95%, if $n > 30,$ then $t^* \approx 2.0.$
Then the margin of error estimating $\mu$ is about $2S/\sqrt{n}.$
For margin of error $M$ small enough to be useful, one can solve for $n$
in the obvious way to to get $n \approx 4S^2/M^2.$

> For example, I simulated a sample of $n = 100$ observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 60, \sigma=3)$ obtaining $\bar X = 59.84,\, S=3.10$ so that a
>   95% confidence interval is $(59.21, 60,56)$ with $M = 0.62.$
>   Because this is a simulation, we know that $\mu = 60$ is covered by
>   the confidence interval. If you were not happy in general with estimates
>   that may be off by about $\pm 0.6,$ then you would need sample sizes
>   above 100. In this case a histogram of the fake data is roughly suggestive
>   of the normal density curve of the population distribution.

[image]

If the population is not approximately normal, then one must rely on
the Central Limit Theorem in order to use this method. For sufficiently
large $n,$ the distribution of $\bar X$ is approximately
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})$ and one may use the confidence
interval above. The $n$ required may be quite large if the population
distribution is strongly right skewed. In many cases $n > 100$
is sufficient for the distribution of $\bar X$ to be near enough
normal that the formula $n \approx 4S^2/M^2$ is of use.

However, of the data show many extreme outliers on the high side, as sometimes
happens in waiting-time distributions, then other kinds of confidence
intervals may be preferable, depending on the type of population distribution
(exponential, gamma, Weibull, and so on). If the shape of the population
distribution is unknown or may vary considerably from one application
to another, then a bootstrap confidence interval may be the best approach.

If you could show histograms of several typical samples, it would be
easier to judge what kind of confidence interval to use.